# Django: check if user liked post and corresponding comments in template

Tags: django, django-templates

In user profile page I am displaying posts and comments of the persons that the user is following. I want to check and display like symbol for the posts and comments liked by user. What is the best way to test if user liked post and comment in the template?

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    nLikes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
nLikes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
```

Post like model:

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='related_post',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
liked_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

comment like model:

```
class CommentLike(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', related_name='related_comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    liked_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

my template will be similar to this. I am adding simplified version here just to make things easy

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
   <div>
     {{ post.text }}
   </div>
   {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
   </div>
     {{ comment.text }}
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What is the best way to check if the post and comment liked by the user? I am thinking of using template tags, is there any better way?

Comment: As I understood you want to show posts that user've been liked. Correct?

Comment: No, If the user liked post and comment then I want to display as liked (Thumbs up symbol in blue color) otherwise I want to display as not liked(Thumbs up in gray color).

Comment: Have you searched for *related key*?

Comment: Check my answer. This should work. But it's beginner level. You should use something more effecient. Try custom template tags. you can write your own template tag, and just paste user_id and post_id in it, and in backend you will proceed it as normall view, and on return you will give html code.

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to correct your models.**

This part is very important, your upcoming headache totally depends on your models. So you have to be especcially careful

```
class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "post"

    post_author = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="post_author_key"
    )
    post_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )
    post_text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    # nLikes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    # Don't store likes count  in model, this is not good for OOP


class PostLike(models.Model):
    class Meta:
            db_table = "post_like"
    post_like_post = models.ForeignKey('Post',
        related_name='post_like_post_key',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    post_like_user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        related_name="post_like_user_key"
    )
    post_like_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "comment"
    comment_post = models.ForeignKey('Post',
        related_name='comment_post_key',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="comment_author_key"
    )
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    comment_created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now
    )
    comment_slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4
    )
    # nLikes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    # Same as likes for post, don't store collectable data in mdoel


class CommentLike(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "comment_like"
    comment_like_comment = models.ForeignKey(
        Comment,
        related_name='comment_like_comment_key',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    comment_like_user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="comment_like_user_key"
    )
    comment_like_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Don't forget to makemigrations. after that, let's assume that in your view you have prepared single post, and now you are using it in your template.
So you want to add ThumbsUp icon to this post, in case **if user have liked this post and leaved comment**

**your_template.html**

```
{{ custom_user }}
{{ post }}

{% for liked in post.post_like_post_key.all %}
    {% if liked.post_like_user_id == custom_user.id %}
        {% for comment in post.comment_post_key.all %}
            {% if comment.comment_author_id == custom_user.id %}
                <fa class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></fa>
            {% else %}
                <fa class="fa fa-thumbs-up disabled"></fa>
            {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <fa class="fa fa-thumbs-up disabled"></fa>
    {% endif %}
```